# NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type: How can I add all the keys from a Objective C NSMutableArray to a Swift NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

When I try to add a key to an Objective C NsMutableDictionary in Swift, I have an error message :
**fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type**

Here is my code :

```
  func fieldsWithFields(fieldsObjC:[NSMutableDictionary]) -> [AnyObject]!
    {
    var fields:[NSMutableDictionary] = []
    let elementsToStore = DB_ListOfValue_manage()
    fields = fieldsObjC

    fields.append([FXFormFieldKey: "drivingLicensePhotoFront",
    FXFormFieldTitle: "Verso",
    FXFormFieldType: FXFormFieldTypeImage,
    FXFormFieldPlaceholder: (self.supplement13 != nil ? self.supplement13! : "0"),
    FXFormFieldHeader: "PHOTO DU PERMIS"])

...
```

Comment: Your literal dictionary inside "append" is not an NSMutableDictionary, types don't match. Either create an actual NSMutableDictionary before appending, or forget Foundation altogether and only use Swift. :)

Comment: Hello :), but I create an actual NSMutableDictionary with var fields:[NSMutableDictionary] = [] ?

Comment: No you don't :). You are declaring an empty array where the items are of *type* NSMutableDictionary, but then in the "append" you're not creating an NSMutableDictionary, you're creating a *literal Swift dictionary*. You would have to actually create an NSMutableDictionary instance before appending it to "fields".

Comment: mmm what I would like is declare a literal Swift dictionary where I can add all the values from the Obj C NSMutableDictionary. How can I do that ?

Comment: What I already said is exactly what you need. Make an instance of an NSMutableDictionary with your literal Swift one. See the NSMutableDictionary doc page to find the right initializer. You can then add more values to it. OR forget NS* and only use Swift.

Comment: Perfect it works. Thank you very much :)